# can't add reference to visual studio project with PostBuild event to the preceding build project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a solution with 10 projects. I put a post build action (a call to a batch file) in the lowest level reference project, a class library. The next project with the original project as a references, can't find the project reference. If I drop the reference and then try to add, i get a cannot add reference message.

I'm thinking it's related to calling a batch file from the postbuild event.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't add references to the .dll rather to the actual project in your solution

Comment: I am trying to add as a project reference, not a dll.

Comment: What's the _"cannot add reference message"_?

Comment: that's it. nothing more; although, it does include the name of the project in the message.  I'm thinking if I use a call batch file instead of batchfile.